# how to retrieve friends' list using facebook connect with iphone app

Tags: iphone, facebook

I'm using facebook connect for my iphone app. It is able to authenticate the user and also publish a comment on the user's wall. But I'm not sure how to retrieve the user's friends list. A sample code will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

-Chandni

Answer (score 3):

In a class that implements the FBRequestDelegate and FBSessionDelegate do this:

```
-(void) getFriends{
        NSString * funcName = @"friends.get";
        [[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:funcName params:nil];
}

- (void) processFriendsQuery:(id) result{
   friends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString * element; 
    gDatabase.userIdList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:MAX_FRIENDS_LIST] autorelease];     

 for (element in result){
    Friend * aFriend = [[[Friend alloc] init]autorelease];  
     NSString * uid = [self dictionaryToUID:element];
     aFriend.userId = (NSMutableString *)  uid;
     [gDatabase.userIdList addObject:aFriend.userId];        
 }
```

and then call it in

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result {
  [self processFriendsQuery:result];    
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I'll try that today.. Also I'm assuming FBConnect does not have any default page to show the Friends list for iPhone the way they have to publish and to login

Comment: So David who will call the getFriends method

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to call your `getFriends` method

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to output a list of friends to the console. I'm still trying to figure  out how to send a message to one of their walls though...

```
 AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


 //Call the request method
 [[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];


// get the array of friends                
NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

// Check that the user has friends
if ([data count] > 0) {

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];    
         for (int i = 0; i < data.count; i++){
          id object = [data objectAtIndex:i];
          [array addObject:[object objectForKey:@"name"]];
}

NSLog(@"list of friends %@", array);
```