# Api Facebook iphone , possible to post to a friend's wall

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-wall

I want to know if it is possible to post to a friend's wall using the iPhone Facebook api.
I have already links explaining how to post on user'wall but not on firend's wall
here are the links :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/facebook

Answer (score 3):

You just have to send your friend's Facebook ID as a parameter under the key "target_id".

OLD SDK: set the FBStream dialog's targetId property.

NEW SDK: set a parameter under the key @"target_id" on the parameters dictionary (when invoking dialog:andParams:andDelegate: on the Facebook object).

Here you have a sample post using the new sdk (the one that uses graph api):

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[params setObject:@"Some text" forKey:@"user_message_prompt"];
[params setObject:@"another text" forKey:@"action_links"];
[params setObject:@"Yet another text" forKey:@"attachment"];
[params setObject:@"SOME FACEBOOK ID" forKey:@"target_id"];

//At some point you need to create the following Facebook instance

[facebook dialog: @"stream.publish"
    andParams: params
    andDelegate: self];
```

I haven't actually tested this code, but this is a pretty straight-forward thing to once you have already posted a message to your wall.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot ,  can you give me  one sample code for loading freind list for target id

Comment: i looking this but its not clear http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121796/how-to-retrieve-friends-list-using-facebook-connect-with-iphone-app

Comment: I think you should open another question for that. I wrote a snippet of code but it's too big for this space. Also, please vote or mark the question as correct if that is the case.