# How to post to a friends Wall using Facebook Graph API for iPhone

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to post something in the users friends wall.

I use this to post into the user wall

```
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

    NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                           @"Always Running",@"text",@"http://itsti.me/",@"href", nil], nil];

    NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];
    NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"a long run", @"name",
                                @"The Facebook Running app", @"caption",
                                @"it is fun", @"description",
                                @"http://itsti.me/", @"href", nil];
    NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Share on Facebook",  @"user_message_prompt",
                                   actionLinksStr, @"action_links",
                                   attachmentStr, @"attachment",nil];

    [facebook dialog:@"feed"
            andParams:params
          andDelegate:self];
```

But i need to post in my friends wall. how can i do this

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126400/api-facebook-iphone-possible-to-post-to-a-friends-wall) they have mentioned about targetId do i have to do something with that.

Comment: Still no answer :(  Someone ans my question..

Comment: 23 days gone and no answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using,

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"[friend_ID]/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

**UPDATE:**

Posting on friends wall will no more work with Graph API. Instead you must use FBDialog.

Comment: Each profile in fb has an id like this 1405135278. You should set that as target_id.

Comment: Did you check your FB account? i posted to ur wall using this code only ;)

Comment: Guys... i want that through my app when i logging to my account and then clicking on any button it should paste that post to my friend. But i wonder how can i take someone's facebook account id through my app and post on their walls. Can you help me plz... :)

Comment: @KingofBliss can we post to multiple people in one single request...? If yes than how.?

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava Its not possible with ios graph api.. check this answer for alternate solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/12006485/433794

Answer (score 0):

@mAc

You have to authorize facebook first. Then you implement 'FBRequestDelegate' methods to your class. Then make a request with graph API as given below

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

Once your request succeeded, api will call the delegate method 'requestDdidLoad',

```
-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {

    NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);

}
```

Form the result you will get the frieds page ID

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)InviteAction:(id)sender  // Button action 
{
    if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                           allowLoginUI:YES
                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                          FBSessionState state,
                                                          NSError *error) {
                                          if (error) {
                                              UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invite friends process cancelled"
                                                                                                  message:nil
                                                                                                 delegate:nil
                                                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                              [alertView show];
                                          } else if (session.isOpen) {
                                              [self InviteAction:sender];
                                          }
                                      }];
        return;
    }

    if (self.friendPickerController == nil) {
        // Create friend picker, and get data loaded into it.
        self.friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
        self.friendPickerController.title = @"Pick Friends";
        self.friendPickerController.delegate = self;
    }

    [self.friendPickerController loadData];
    [self.friendPickerController clearSelection];

    [self presentViewController:self.friendPickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) performPublishAction:(void (^)(void)) action
{
    if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound)
    {
        [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                              defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                                if (!error) {
                                                    action();
                                                } else if (error.fberrorCategory != FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled){
                                                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Permission denied"
                                                                                                        message:@"Unable to get permission to post"
                                                                                                       delegate:nil
                                                                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                    [alertView show];
                                                }
                                            }];
    } else {
        action();
    }

}



- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
    self.loggedInUser = user;
}


- (void)facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableString *text = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (id<FBGraphUser> user in self.friendPickerController.selection)
    {

        if ([text length]) {
            [text appendString:@","];
        }
        [text appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",user.id]];
    }

    //For post to friend's wall
    NSDictionary *params = @{
                            @"name" : @"Hello Please checkout this app",
                             @"caption" : @" IOS APP",
                            @"description" : @"",
                             @"picture" : @"logo@2x.png",
                             @"link" : @"http:www.google.com",
                             @"to":text,

                             };


    // Invoke the dialog
    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                          parameters:params
                                             handler:
     ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
             UIAlertView *alertshow = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Failed" message:@"Failed to Post" delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alertshow show];
         } else {
             if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted)
             {
                NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
                 UIAlertView *alertshow = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Failed"   message:@"Failed to post on your friend wall" delegate:Nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alertshow show];
             } else {
                 NSLog(@"Story published.");
                 UIAlertView *alertshow = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Posted on Friend wall" delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alertshow show];
            }
         }}];



    [self fillTextBoxAndDismiss:text.length > 0 ? text : @"<None>"];
}

- (void)facebookViewControllerCancelWasPressed:(id)sender {
    [self fillTextBoxAndDismiss:@"<Cancelled>"];
}

- (void)fillTextBoxAndDismiss:(NSString *)text
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```