# Posting Messages in Walls of Multiple Friends

Tags: objective-c, facebook, post, ios4

I am developing an application in which i want to post messages on Wall of multiple users on facebook like "Its your turn To play a particular game".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only way of doing it is using server side script for publishing on friends feed

you can use the Graph API to POST to the friend's feed by issuing a POST request to the `/PROFILE_ID/feed` scope (while PROFILE_ID is the friend's facebook id - or username)
furher information on:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts (under create segment)

in order to publish on multiple friends feeds - you need to do this in a loop (highly not recommended - facebook automated rating doesn't like it because it seems like spam, and your application might get blocked)

another way (instead of loop in your code) is using the batch request concept as described in [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) for creating multiple graph api calls at once

in order to publish post on befhalf of the user he will have to grant you with `publish_stream` permission (or even better - `publish_actions`). further details about extended permissions can be found here - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

EDIT:
Since February 2013 it is no longer possible to post on other users wall through the graph API. So you can see this answer as not relevant anymore

Comment: can you please tell me how can i create batch request for multiple ids? please refere to link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315522/query-to-send-a-status-to-multiple-friend

Comment: ist deprecated since february

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/#february-2013

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do multiple post via IOS FB SDK. Even though the docs say that you can use  "To" parameter of the api, its not allowing to post on multiple walls with single call.

Instead you need to do it in multiple calls. Or you can send a Notification via Game requests to multiple users. But posting on walls seems to be not possible at the moment.

Comment: That bug report was about the 'send' dialog - and isn't a bug, it's intentional behaviour

Comment: Actually its the same with feed dialog as well.At the moment i was unable to find that bug report. Will update once i find it.btw according to Send dialog docs we can send multiple posts but its not possible according to the bug reported. (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/)

Comment: Feed dialog also isn't supposed to have multiple recipients. even posting multiple stories simultaneously used to be expressly against policy, though now it's simply enforced by the spam systems and technically allowed.

Comment: @IGY : you are right regarding feed dialog. Let me correct my answer.Thanks for the info.