# query to send a status to multiple friend

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api

As referenced from link [Facebook FQL multiquery in iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022522/facebook-fql-multiquery-in-ios-sdk) i need to fire multiquery where a particular status will send to selected uid in an array. I am unable to create query.
Here is my code:

```
  NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString 
   stringWithFormat:@"HERE NEED QUERY TO SEND STATUS TO SELECTED UIDS"], @"queries",nil];
  [_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"fql.multiquery" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST"   
  andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Forget it, posting to walls other than the current user’s per API will be disabled soon (Feb 2013) anyways.

Comment: @CBroe this will come in effect if i select "February 2013 Breaking Changes:" enabled in advance option at my facebook app

Comment: This will come into effect Feb. 2013, without the option to turn it back on again. So IMHO a waste of time trying to develop anything in that direction now.