# How to send direct message to friend on Facebook iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios5, fbconnect

How to send direct message by dialog to friend on Facebook iPhone sdk ? I have been tried this code but not properly working?

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"I'm using the MyFBTest App", @"name",@"http://listentowebby.com/wp-content/themes/cw/images/facebook.png", @"link",nil];



AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[delegate facebook] dialog:@"send"
                  andParams:params
                andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: What do you want ? send a message or post on friends wall ?

Answer (score 3):

you can't send direct message in mobile devices says facebook documentation [send dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/)

and the method you are using will only send the request, and if the user to whom sending request, has installed the app, then it will able to read the message else not.

one other way to convey your message is to post on friends wall, for which you may refer to this thread [facebook ios post on friend's wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126400/api-facebook-iphone-possible-to-post-to-a-friends-wall)

Comment: which one? post on friends wall?

Comment: please explain this link....https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Comment: read second paragraph You should specify a URL, and you can pre-populate a user in the ‘to’ field. The Send Dialog does not require any extended permissions. This Dialog is currently not supported on mobile devices