# IOS send message through facebook

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api, facebook-chat

i'm creating an app that help people meet with new people , and i would like to give the user an option to send message through facebook to new people they see in the app , is there any way of doing it?

I tried to search online but I found nothing.

I need that the app will open a send message dialog or something like that , and the rest of the conversation will continue on facebook.

thanks for the help , and sorry if this question was asked and i didn't see it or understood it.

Comment: well I'm new in this all Xcode and facebook programming , so i went and tried to search online for a way to do it , a lot of the answers said yes, but i didn't find anything in the facebook api , so again , thats why I'm asking , and if its not OK to ask something so for what is this site?

Comment: Generally for troubleshooting coding errors.

[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212270/iphone-app-send-facebook-message-or-post-to-friends-walls) is a thread that will tell you what you need.

Like I suggested before, you may wish to learn more about Xcode and Facebook's API.

Answer (score 3):

Related to this question:[sending a private message to your friends via Facebook IOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665476/sending-a-private-message-to-your-friends-via-facebook-ios-sdk)

But, you can find the information you're looking for at the links below. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ui-controls

Basically, if your user is logged in on your app with Facebook, then you have a few more tools/options to use to accomplish your task.
If your user is not logged in on your app with Facebook, then it is much more restricted.

Comment: well i have looked in all of those links but found nothing , it only says how to post on friends wall .
sorry for the trouble but i don't know what to do

Comment: Ever able to accomplish this Eilon?