# Publish message to friend's wall from iPhone app

Tags: iphone, facebook, post

I would like my iPhone app to be able to post a static message to a user's friend's facebook wall.  Something like it shows the static message up above, and then a place to type in friends name and shows suggested friends.  Is this done through graph api, or is there a key of permissions that the POST method can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126400/api-facebook-iphone-possible-to-post-to-a-friends-wall) might be what you are after.

From the link:

"You just have to send your friend's Facebook ID as a parameter under the key "target_id".

set a parameter under the key @"target_id" on the parameters dictionary (when invoking dialog:andParams:andDelegate: on the Facebook object).

Here you have a sample post using the new sdk (the one that uses graph api):

```
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[params setObject:@"Some text" forKey:@"user_message_prompt"];
[params setObject:@"another text" forKey:@"action_links"];
[params setObject:@"Yet another text" forKey:@"attachment"];
[params setObject:@"SOME FACEBOOK ID" forKey:@"target_id"];

//At some point you need to create the following Facebook instance

[facebook dialog: @"stream.publish"
    andParams: params
    andDelegate: self];
```

Comment: I've seen that one, but it seems to require you know the facebook id.  Is there anyway to pull up the window with a list of suggested friends or type to add a friend to send it to?

Comment: The following should return a list of the logged in user's friends.  [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];

Comment: After you return the list of friends, is there a way to then present the message with the list of friends as recipients?

Answer (score 0):

you first need to request the friend list and then provide an interface in your app where user could select which friend's wall he want to write on... :)
afterwards, you can pass the selected friends id to the dialog you are presenting to the user... Atleast I am used to do it this way and it seems to be a pretty standard way of publishing something on user's wall...
hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but how do you request the friend list?

Comment: Thanks, but how do you request the friend list?

Comment: To get list of friends you can use
[link](https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends)
--->

   [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andParams:nil
   andDelegate:self];



To know more about all the possible API please read
 [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)